# Why do I have to spawn a new shell when doing remote sudo ssh commands to get proper file permissions?

Tags: ssh, sudo

I'm using password-less key based login with sudo to execute remote commands. I have figured out that I have to spawn a new shell to execute commands that write to root areas of the remote file system. But, I would like a clear explanation of exactly why this is the case?

This fails:

```
sudo -u joe ssh example.com "sudo echo test > /root/echo_test"
```

with:
bash: /root/echo_test: Permission denied

This works fine:

```
sudo -u joe ssh example.com "sudo bash -c 'echo test > /root/echo_test'"
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the same reason that a local `sudo echo test >/root/echo_test` will fail (if you are not root) -- the redirection is done by the shell (not the sudo or echo command) which is running as the normal user.  `sudo` only runs the echo command as root.

With `sudo -u joe ssh example.com "sudo echo test > /root/echo_test"`, the remote shell is running as a normal user (probably joe) and does not have permission to write to the file.  Using an extra bash invokation works, because `sudo` then runs bash as root (rather than echo), and that bash *can* open the file and do the redirect.